# I am beginner in R and I'm trying to solve a system of equations but when i run i get error in R

Tags: r, statistics, rstudio

```
# my error : Error in F[1] <- n/(X[0]) - sum(log(1 + Y^exp(X[1] + X[2] * x))) : replacement has length zero

set.seed(16)

#Inverse Transformation on CDF

n=100

SimRRR.f <- function(100, lambda=1,tau)) {
  x= rnorm(100,0,1)
  tau= exp(-1-x)
  u=runif(100)
  y= (1/(u^(1/lambda)-1))^(1/tau)
  y
}
Y<-((1/u)-1)^exp(-1-x)

# MLE for Simple Linear Regresion

# System of equations

library(rootSolve)
library(nleqslv)

model <- function(X){
  F <- numeric(length(X)) 
  F[1] <- n/(X[0])-sum(log(1+Y^exp(X[1]+X[2]*x)))
  F[2] <- 2*n -(X[0]+1)*sum(exp(X[1]+X[2]*x))*Y^( exp(X[1]+X[2]*x))*log(Y)/(1+ Y^( exp(X[1]+X[2]*x)))

  F[3] <- sum(x) + sum(x*log(Y))*exp(X[1]+X[2]*x) -(X[0]+1)*X[1]*sum(exp(X[1]+X[2]*x)*Y^(exp(X[1]+X[2]*x)*log(Y)))/(1+ Y^( exp(X[1]+X[2]*x)))

# Solution

  F

}

startx <- c(0.5,3,1) # start the answer search here
answers<-as.data.frame(nleqslv(startx,model))
```

Comment: there is a lot more going on here than just that, but good catch. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you define `x`, `u`, `tau` and `y` inside the `SimRRR` function, but are trying to define `Y` in terms of them outside the function.

Using a function, you give it input, and you get back output.  All the other variables defined in the course of the function doing its job go away at the end.  As it stands, `Y` should be a series of NAs (unless you defined the above variables in the global environment as you were working on your function...)

Try the following functions, see if they do the job:

```
# I usually put all my library calls together at the beginning of the script.
library(rootSolve)
library(nleqslv)

x = rnorm(n,0,1) # see below for why this is pulled out.
SimRRR.f <- function(x, lambda=1,tau)) { # 100 can't be by itself in the function call.  everything in there needs to be attached to a variable.
  n <- length(x)
  tau= exp(-1-x)
  u=runif(n)
  y= (1/(u^(1/lambda)-1))^(1/tau)
  y
}
Y_sim = SimRRR.f(n = 100, lambda = 1, tau = 1) # pick the right tau, it's never defined here.
```

Your second function has more issues.  Namely, it relies on `x`, which is not defined anywhere that can be found.  Either you *need* `x` from the previous function, or you really meant `X`.  I'm going to assume you do need the values of `x`, since `X` is only of length 3.  This is why I pulled it out of the last function call - we need it now.

#### [Update]

It's also been pointed out in the comments that the indexing here is wrong.  I didn't catch that previously (and the `F` elements are defined correctly).  I *think* I've fixed the indexing issues too now:

```
model <- function(X, Y, x){  # If you use x and Y in the function, define them here.
  n <- length(x)

  F <- numeric(length(X)) 
  F[1] <- n/(X[1])-sum(log(1+Y^exp(X[2]+X[3]*x)))
  F[2] <- 2*n -(X[1]+1)*sum(exp(X[2]+X[3]*x))*Y^( exp(X[2]+X[3]*x))*log(Y)/(1+ Y^( exp(X[2]+X[3]*x)))

  F[3] <- sum(x) + sum(x*log(Y))*exp(X[2]+X[3]*x) -(X[1]+1)*X[2]*sum(exp(X[2]+X[3]*x)*Y^(exp(X[2]+X[3]*x)*log(Y)))/(1+ Y^( exp(X[2]+X[3]*x)))  

# Solution

  F

}
```

I'm not familiar with the `nleqslv` package, but unless there is a method defined to convert it to a data frame, that might not go so well.  I'd make sure everything else is working before the conversion.

```
startx <- c(0.5,3,1) # start the answer search here
answers <- nleqslv(startx,model, Y = Y_sim, x = x)
answer_df <- as.data.frame(answers)
```